# Get next / previous record in ASP.NET Core MVC using Dapper

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm pulling list data into a grid, and viewing them one-by-one in a "detail view". I'm trying to add a Next/Previous button that will allow me to easily navigate between the details of each item from my list.

Here is the code I'm using within my controller

```
var nextID = _movieRepository.GetAll()
                             .OrderBy(i => i.movie_id)
                             .SkipWhile(i => i.movie_id != i.movie_id)
                             .Skip(1)
                             .Select(i => i.movie_id);

ViewBag.NextID = nextID;
```

Within my breakpoint, it is only returning "nextID = NULL" which means it does not generate the appropriate next Record ID at the end of my URL. Note: I am using the Linq namespace in my controller, but I'm not using EF. This is the simple code I have in my view.

```
<a href="/@ViewData["Controller"]/@ViewData["Action"]/@ViewBag.nextID"> Next Movie </a>
```

I've been Googling, trying different methods, different combination of the Skip/SkipWhile/Select/FirstOrDefault, and nothing has worked. Any assistance or insight on this is much appreciated.

Comment: If you order by _movie_id_, the next one after the id passed could be retrieved just with where and firstordefault. Am I missing something?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you need help with: LINQ expression, generating URL via `ViewData` and `ViewBag`, or other? What are you expecting to return from the LINQ statement?

Comment: I'm not getting any value in my ViewBag with the Linq expression specified above to retrieve the next record for the "Next" button.

Comment: After some fiddling, I can get it to still return "NULL" or it returns the entire details of my record - instead of simply the record ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have a bug in your code

```
  .SkipWhile(i => i.movie_id != i.movie_id)
```

is always false, so you will always have all records minus one, instead of one record.

I assume that you have movie_id and you need the next larger id after this , so try this code

```
var nextID = _movieRepository.GetAll()
                             .OrderBy(i => i.movie_id)
                             .Where(i => i.movie_id > movie_Id )
                             .Select(i => i.movie_id)
                             .FirstOrDefault();
```

this query will return next movie_id after current movie_id